# ElasticSearch: multi_match with cross_field type - at least one matched token in each field

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch

I am working with ElasticSearch 8.11.  I have a query as follows:

```
{
              query: {
                function_score: {
                  query: {
                    bool: {
                      must: [{
                               multi_match: {
                                 query: 'dave liverpool',
                                 fields: ['name', 'address'],
                                 type: "cross_fields",
                                 minimum_should_match: 2
                               }
                             }]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
```

If I pass a query of `dave liverpool` into the query, I want to be able to ensure that the query matches at least one token in the address field.  So `dave` would match on `name` and `liverpool` would match on `address`.  What I don't want is results where `dave` and `liverpool` both occur in the `name` field.  The query is dynamic and I am using the Ruby elasticsearch client.  I have used a two-word query here but the query may in reality be longer.

At the moment, the query also returns results where all tokens appear in just one field.  I only want results where at least one of the tokens appears in the second field.

The mappings for the two fields are as follows:

```
"name_comma_analyzed":{"type":"text","analyzer":"comma"}

"address_comma_analyzed":{"type":"text","analyzer":"comma"}
```

and the analyzer is as follows:

```
"comma":{"pattern":"(?:,|\\s)+","type":"pattern_replace","replacement":" "}
```

How can I go about getting the results that I want?

Comment: Please provide the code you are currently using

Comment: The query is posted above.